# How to create a file named "0" on hosting server (CentOS)

Tags: node.js, linux, file, ext3

When I create a new file named `0` on my VPS, I always get a directory `0` instead of the file.

It happens in the case when I upload a file `0` or create a file by `touch 0`.

It seems that `0` has a special meaning on `ext3` Linux file system.

Could you advise on it?

Additionally, how can I create a `0` file on Node.js?

Comment: `touch 0` Works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually not an error and was related to the UI issue `File Manager` in Cpanel.

In `File Manager` it (`0`) looks like a `folder`, but it must be a file. I confirmed it by `cat 0`.